# How to jump to a different section of a page?

Tags: html

Is there a way to jump to a section on a different page when you click a link? I am a beginner, so I don't know JavaScript etc.

Comment: Yes, if the other page has a content section with an id, you can have a link that goes to newpage.html#id_name If you use js then the possibilities are limitless

Answer (score 2):

You don't need anything but HTML:

```
<a href="other-page.html#example">
```

and (on the other page):

```
<div id="example">
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the part in a `<div>` and and define an ID to it. Like this:

```
<div id="loc">
```

Band then add an anchor tag with `href` set to that id:

```
<a href="#loc">
```

This will take the screen to that part the the referenced ID.